# Firebase Storage - download image using nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage

I am having an issue getting this to work. What I have so far is this:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
//
var serviceAccount = require("./firebase-adminsdk.json");
//
admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "https://invites.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "invites.appspot.com" // Used for Storage Ref
});

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {

    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    bucket.getFiles(function(err, files) {

        if (!err) {

            console.log(files);

        }

    });

}
```

The code above returns a json object with all the files in the Firebase Storage bucket.

What I am wanting to do is download a specific image from the bucket and pass it along to an  element in a html file, which I have tried endlessly and wanted to see if anyone has done this already!?

UPDATE:
I try using the following:

```
var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
var file = bucket.file('megamuilah_med.png');

file.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {

    if (!err) {

        console.log(files)

    }

    console.log("Download to get file list!?: ", url); 

});
```

The above throws the following error: file.getDownloadURL is not a function!?

Comment: Please read the documentation for downloading files.  The Admin SDK just wraps the Google Cloud node SDK, so use the node SDK documentation to understand the APIs.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects

Comment: @DougStevenson the link you provided d/l the info to a file. Is it possible to download it and insert it as a url into an <img> tag to "download"

Comment: No, that's not possible.  Use a download URL for that.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the question; `getDownloadURL` throws an error?!

Comment: @DougStevenson can you provide an example please!?

Comment: There are examples in the Cloud Storage node API documentation.